# How to send float through serial port in c#?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have two float now,say f1 and f2. I want to send them to my micro controller through my computer serial port, how should I do it?
My understanding is we need to convert f1 and f2 to binary first,then send to micro, after that cnvert back to float again. So I am confused that HOW DO I CONVERT FLOAT TO BINARY BEFORE I SEND THEM OUT? My code now is

```
    b1 = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(f1);
    b2 = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(f2);
```

Comment: what does your microcontroller support?  often with micros you end up using fixed point,  but some are more capable than others.

Comment: hi thanks for your remind, my micro can support float!

Comment: Serial ports, like all data channels, really don't care about data types.  They simply transfer bytes (of data and/or text).  And when you transfer binary data (instead of line formatted text e.g. ASCII), there should be a data/message protocol in place in order to sort out the byte ordering and the start & end of the data/message.  Otherwise you risk message synchronization issues.

Comment: *"I have two float"* -- Presumably you mean two variables, which would already be (multi-byte) binary values.  You cannot convert a **float** data type to a "binary", just as you cannot convert a **long int** or **char** to a "binary".  For maximum *portability*, sending data converted to numeric text strings is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the endianness of your microcontroller's architecture. But roughly speaking you need to do this:

1. Convert your float to a 4-byte array. You're on the right track, although my C# is very rusty.
2. Send them one by one to the microcontroller
3. If your microcontroller supports floating point representation you could cast the four-byte array into a float:

   ```
   byte array[4]; // Pre-allocate your array
   getBytesFromSerial(array); // Fill the array with values from serial port
   float converted = 0;
   memcpy(&converted, array, 4);
   /** Now "converted" holds the float value */
   ```

Now that will work only if the endianness of your uC is consistent with the order in which you are sending the data. If that doesn't work try sending the byte array in inverted order. And please mind the error checking!

Comment: hi thank you for your reply!  so how can i do your step 1 and 2? i.e.Convert your float to a 4-byte array. then Send them one by one to the microcontroller.  my code as following:

Comment: ---private byte[] b1, b2;                                                       float f1 = float.Parse(S1), f2 = float.Parse(S2);
            b1 = new byte[4];
            b2 = new byte[4];
            b1 = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(f1);
            b2 = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(f2);                               serialPort.Write(b1, 0, 4);
                serialPort.Write(b2, 0, 4);  I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO PUT THE CODE IN CORRECT FORMAT HERE, SORRY!!!!!!