# C# send float throughserial port to avr

Tags: c#

Hi i have a problem with sending float variable from PC to AVR. I want to sending value from trackbar and uC send this value back(for sure that is everything is ok), so with int variable is ok but with floats isn't - in text box i have undefined values(for example i send from trackbar 7.1 and i get 51.0 or 205.0). Here are my codes from uC and c#:

C:

```
    while(1)
   {
    variable=  uart_getchar();
    sprintf(bufor,"%.1f\n",variable);
    uart_puts(bufor);
   }
```

C#:

```
private void trackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        variable = (float)trackBar1.Value /10;
        Wyslane.AppendText("Serwo_1: "+variable.ToString()+"\r\n");
        byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(variable);
        serialPort1.Write(b, 0, 4);

    }

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        message = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(display));

    }

    private void display(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Odebrane.AppendText(message);

    }
```

Comment: Have a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354428/how-to-send-float-through-serial-port-in-c)

Comment: I think that you should make sure of receive 4 bytes (wait if necessary) and after that use bitconverter again to convert from these 4 bytes buffer to float doing the reverse process...

Comment: How can i do this?

Comment: There is not enough information here to know what's wrong. Your C# code appears to be sending binary data, while the C code seems to be sending text. This may or may not be a problem, but without seeing the C code to receive the `float` value, there's no way to know.

Comment: I receive every value by uart_getchar and than i use sprintf to send back